# d3 sankey svg text tspan - on click not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, sankey-diagram

I am using a fairly typical d3 sankey, with one minor change to extending the label of the rect to include 3 lines of text using tspan... the code looks like this:

```
<svg>
  <g>
   <g></g>
   <g></g>
   ...
  </g>
  <g>
    <g class="node" transform="translate(1224,183.54665552874204)">
      <rect height="3.1713693459563146" width="15" class="svg-rect-17" style="stroke: none;">
        <title>1,079</title>
      </rect>
      <text text-anchor="end" class="svg-text-17" transform="">
        <tspan x="-10" text-anchor="end" y="3.1713693459563146" class="">1,079</tspan>
        <tspan x="20" text-anchor="end" y="43.171369345956315" class="calc-total">Execution Fallout</tspan>
        <tspan x="20" text-anchor="end" y="73.17136934595632" class="calc-total">4,904</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
    <g></g>
    ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

I have attempted to make the items with class "calc-total" clickable with adding the following to the tspan append call:

```
.on('click',function(d) { console.log('label',d) });
```

Which can be seen in context here:

```
//sankey node text block
var tspan = node
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
        return "svg-text-"+d.id+" svg-text-" + d.type;
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return (d.id==0) ? "rotate(270,10,20)" : ""});


//node data
tspan.append("tspan")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return calcXP(d, 'data', false)
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
        return calcAnc(d, 'data', false);
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return calcYP(d, 'data', false)
    })
    .text(function (d) {
        return numberWithCommas(d.total);
    })
    .attr("class", function (d) {
        return "data-" + d.type + " data-" + d.type + (d.subtype ? "-" + d.subtype : "");
    });

//node label total
tspan.filter(function (d) {
    return d.subtype && d.subtype == 'undefined';
}).append("tspan")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return calcXP(d, 'label', true)
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
        return calcAnc(d, 'label', true);
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return calcYP(d, 'label', true)
    })
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.category;
    })
    .attr("class", "calc-total")
    .on('click',function(d) { console.log('label',d) });

//node data total
tspan.filter(function (d) {
    return d.subtype && d.subtype == 'undefined';
}).append("tspan")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return calcXP(d, 'data', true)
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
        return calcAnc(d, 'data', true);
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return calcYP(d, 'data', true)
    })
    .text(function (d) {
        return numberWithCommas(totalByCat[d.category]);
    })
    .attr("class", "calc-total")
    .on('click',function(d) { console.log('data',d) });
```

I have also added the following CSS based on other stackoverflow findings:

```
svg text, svg text tspan {
    pointer-events: none;
    display: block;
}
```

No matter what I do, I can not get the text/tspan to click.  I've tried with jquery referencing classes, I've tried putting it on text, and the tspan append areas... I'm stumped.  I would love some help.

Once again, my goal is to have both tspans with class = "calc-total" clickable and run a JS method (not link).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: BUMP.  I would be happy even with directional help linking SVG Text/TSpan elements, the styling that may help or be hindering... etc.  Anything :). I know its possible to do, driving myself crazy trying to find it.  cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that have interest in this functionality;  I did get this to work, however, it's not very elegant.

I could never get the tspan or text to call javascript on the sankey. Strangely enough, I have easily made this work on the collapsible tree and other d3 svg elements, but the sankey fought me for days.

I ended up placing an svg Rect over the top of the text I wanted clickable.  Styled it to be transparent.  Added the `.call(call(d3.behavior.drag()...` to the rect, and fired my action on dragstart, and doing nothing for drag.

Ew... but it works.